# Texture assigned to more than one object renders differently

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been looking at this question - 
[copy the size and scale a texture is mapped by, from one object to another](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40943/copy-the-size-and-scale-a-texture-is-mapped-by-from-one-object-to-another) - but concluded it's not the problem. The question deals with UV map disparities relating to scale and origin. I believe my problem is different?

I've tried assigning the material this way too: [Adding textures to more than one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/adding-textures-to-more-than-one-object) to no avail.

I have two cubes, one created by duplicating the other and scaling. Both have the same material assigned. The first cube had the material assigned when I duplicated it. I have unwrapped each using ***Unwrap*** > ***Project from view***

I've explored whether it's a lighting issue - though essentially by deleting any previously set-up lights and adding some fresh default ones.

1. Have I assessed the problem correctly? (It's not a material/texture scale/origin issue)
2. Any ideas what the problem might be related to?

Note: Blender Render

Images below - the stand with the vases on it should be the exact same texture as the wall behind.

[image: scene and uv maps]
[image: detail to show textures]

Comment: Can you show your material and texture panels? Maybe also upload a .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Is the scale applied for the duplicated and scaled object ?

Comment: @MrZak You mean scale in the materials/textures panel? I've been looking for differences, but my understanding is that the texture settings don't take object specific over rides.. (I may be wrong). Or is there a scale associated with the object I should know about... can you tell I'm struggling? Thanks for the interest btw

Comment: I meant [applying scale of the object](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply%20transforms#apply-object-transformations); you can see its values in the *Properties* shelf (*Transform* rollout). See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: Ooohhh, can't believe none of the tutorials I've been working through have explained this one. I'd have never turned up that question by searching. Thank you @MrZak, you're a good'un.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object which has another appearence of the texture was scaled in Object mode, while its UV map was left as it was from the original one. [Apply the transforms](http://blender-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply), redo (or change) the UV map and the texture will act in the same way on both objects.

**What happens when duplicating unwrapped object**

The original object was unwrapped.
Then the duplicate was created. It derived the UV map from the original object, and that UV map was the same as there.
After that the duplicate was scaled to fit the scene specifics.

The difference consists in that the duplicate was scaled in Object mode, and most likely was scaled non-uniformly (e.g. by Z axis more than by X). These transforms weren't applied to the object data. Hence the mesh was different from one unfolded in the UV map, and that's where the difference came from.

Generally, if you scale by one axis in Edit mode, you'll get non-unform texture distribution too. However you will be able to change that by unwrapping once more.

For details about the possible cases when you need applying transforms refer to [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)